# Bootstrap's modal data attribute not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

**Problem**

I have two buttons that shows the modal with `data-number=10` and `data-number=20`. The title updates but when I'm alerting the data content, It shows the value of the button that was clicked first.

Please see this demo:

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5py74md0/)

**Expectation**

It should alert `10` when I click the modal's button of <kbd>10</kbd> . and `20` when I click the modal's button of <kbd>20</kbd>

Comment: Can't see buttons on the modal

Comment: Sorry my problem isn't clear. But what I mean is when you click the button inside the modal. @DarrenSweeney

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated your fiddle, checkout this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/5py74md0/1/).

I have changed `modal.find('#btn-demo').attr('data-number', number);` to `modal.find('#btn-demo').data('number', number);`.

I've also fix the html, the `.modal-sm` was in a wrong place. It should be on `.modal-dialog` level.